# Can't access object property from C++ file (Cocos2D/Box2d)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm implementing a Contact Listener with Box2d which is a C++ .mm file.

Whenever two bubble's collide, I want to know so I can execute something. Here is my code:

```
void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{

    b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
    if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {
        BubbleSprite* bNodeA = (BubbleSprite*)bodyA->GetUserData();
        BubbleSprite* bNodeB = (BubbleSprite*)bodyB->GetUserData();

        BOOL oneIsBeingTouched;
        if(bNodeA.isDrag == YES || bNodeB.isDrag == YES) oneIsBeingTouched = YES;
...
```

BubbleSprite's have the `property BOOL isDrag` which indicates whether or not they are currently being dragged by a user. The problem I get is:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[CCSprite isDrag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed504a0'
```

BubbleSprite is a subclass of CCSprite. isDrag is properly declared and synthesized in its file. Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on? Thanks

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968425/fxlabel-crash-with-uilabel-error is another similiar problem today, fixed by restarting xcode and reimporting certain files to project.

Comment: You mention that this code is for "whenever two bubble's collide", but you are not checking that the collision is between two bubbles. If every body in the world is a bubble then this would still be ok, but otherwise you cannot assume that the collision is between two bubbles.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a getter, Create your property like so.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isDrag) BOOL dragging;
```

and of course, `@synthesize` it. Now you can use `-setDragging:` and `[bNodeA isDrag]`. Nothing serious, but should make for easier to understand code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 if (bNodeA.drag == YES) ...
```

or

```
if ([bNodeA isDrag] == YES) ...
```

Comment: Same error. Unrecognized selector on CCSprite. It should be run on a BubbleSprite...

Comment: Are you adding `drag` property yourself with subclassing? Neither [`CCSprite`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_sprite.html) nor [`CCNode`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_node.html) have it.

Comment: Yes, isDrag is the property name. As I mentioned, BubbleSprite is a subclass of CCSprite.

Comment: if you named the property `isDrag` it will be accessible via `[node isIsDrag]`. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864239/using-a-bool-property

Comment: Ah, interesting, didn't know about the "is" prepending. Anyway, I renamed it to just "drag" for simplicity. However, I still get the same message. Its asking a CCSprite for the drag property when it should be asking a BubbleSprite and then throwing the unrecognized selector error. Not sure why...Thanks

Comment: do you by any chance call `[super isDrag]` in `BubbleSprite` implementation? Can you post declaration and implementation of this property?