# FXLabel crash with UILabel error

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, subclass

I am trying to set up FXLabel https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXLabel in my project but i get an error i cant explain. I am using Interface Builder to manage the property.

.h File

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet FXLabel *titleLabel;
```

.m File

```
self.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.8f];
self.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 2.0f);
self.titleLabel.shadowBlur = 1.0f;
self.titleLabel.innerShadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.8f];
self.titleLabel.innerShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 2.0f);
```

.xbi File

[image]
[image]

When trying to compile & run an error gets thrown in this line

```
self.titleLabel.innerShadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.8f];
```

and the **error** looks like that:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[UILabel setInnerShadowColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to 
instance 0x6e56180'
```

i guess somehow the compiler thinks it is a UILabel instead of an FXLabel (which it clearly is).
i cant find a work around it, any ideas what might be the problem or what i could try?

thanks in advance
sebastian

Comment: add the following 
if ([titleLabel isKindOfClass:[FXLabel class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Is FXLabel");
    } and post what is the value

Comment: thank you for taking the time. 
somehow it solved itself after restarting xcode twice and re-adding the FXLabel files to my project... strange :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean & Build + Restarting XCode solved the problem.