# UISwitch on vs ison

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties, uiswitch

I'm perusing the `UISwitch` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/on), specifically determining whether a switch is on or off.

Most resources suggest using `isOn` for this, but the docs give more prominence to `on`:

> on
>
> A Boolean value that determines the off/on state of the switch.
>
> @property(nonatomic, getter=isOn) BOOL on

What does this definition mean, exactly? It reads as though there is a property 'on' with a renamed getter? What is the purpose of this? Why not just use `on`?

And if the setter is `isOn`, why can I access `on` at all?

I have similar confusion regarding `isEditing` and `editing` - is the same pattern in play there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isOn) BOOL on
```

It means that property is called `on`, but getter is `isOn`. So whatever you call, in your code methods `isOn` will be called

I suggest that getter is named isOn, because it is good style of code convention to start boolean properties with is...

[Here is nice sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864239/using-a-bool-property)

As for me to start all boolean properties with `is` is very useful, because when you use your class, you can write the name of the instance variable of your class , than write `is` and XCode will show you all the boolean properties..

Comment: So why not simply call the property isOn and have setIsOn? And why make 'On' also accessible?