# Setup BOOL property in Model

Tags: objective-c

Customizing an iOS app in objective-c. Not super familiar with the language, and this simple task of setting up a boolean property has taken me too long.

Can anybody offer some advice here?

**Video.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * hasCustomThumbnail;
```

**Video.m**

```
@implementation Video
     @dynamic hasCustomThumbnail;
@end
```

**OtherFile** referencing the video

```
// have tried these two an many other things...
video.hasCustomThumbnail = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
video.hasCustomThumbnail = @NO;
```

The error I get no matter how many dozens of ways I've tried this is:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Video setHasCustomThumbnail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c0004925c0'
```

Have tried many suggestions including this: [Using a BOOL property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864239/using-a-bool-property)

I also know the video is referenced correctly because autocomplete suggests "hasCustomThumbnail" as I start typing.

I simply cannot believe how hard OBJ-c is making this :-)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the super class of `Video`? How is `Video` declared?

Comment: @alexr101 pls check my answer.

Comment: Is `Video` the representation of a CoreData object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have declared it as **@dynamic**. Just remove this line from the Video.m. Xcode will automatically synthesize the getters and setters.

either of this works.

```
[obj setHasCustomThumbnail:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]];
obj.hasCustomThumbnail = [NSNumber numberWithBool:true];
```

> @dynamic just tells the compiler that the getter and setter methods
>   are implemented not by the class itself but somewhere else (like the
>   superclass or will be provided at runtime).
>
> @synthesize will generate getter and setter methods for your property.

So when you define a property with **@dynamic**, either your superclass or runtime should provide the necessary getter and setter. here no one has provided anything, that is the reason it is saying the **unrecognized selector** sent to an instance. This error will come only if it couldn't able to find a proper method for the object. Hope this will clear your doubts.

> one practical use of @dynamic is that when you inherit your class from
>   NSManagedObject, the core data will provide the setter and getters for
>   the properties.

Comment: It works, man. I have the project with an example too. The error is pretty straightforward.remove the @dynamic from Video.m. By default, all the properties will be synthesized. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences

Comment: updated with more explanation. Mark it if your issue resolved. Otherwise, let me know or comment.

Comment: My bad Kumar, I rushed through the answer this morning, but did not read the synthesize suggestion. Replacing dynamic with synthesize did the trick. Thank you very much you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to BOOL or NSNumber. It is due to your calling setIsCustomThumbnail on class Video.

Either you are doing `video.isCustomThumbnail =` or `[video setIsCustomThumbnail:]` but your class does not declare this `isCustomThumbnail`. From your code seems you mispelled `isCustomThumbnail` as **has**CustomThumbnail.

So make up your mind and use single name.

Comment: I can see where ur coming with this. But thats wrong. I changed the name a couple of times during all my experimenting but all the names currently match that was just a typo in my question.

Comment: Then correct the typo for the next person trying to answer your question.